# Passing C-arrays of different sizes to templated function taking 2 identical parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, stl

I have a templated function `func` as follows which takes two parameters of the same type (usually two STL containers of *the same type but different sizes*). I want to make it work with C-arrays of *the same type but different sizes* too.

```
template<class T>
void func(const T& a, const T& b) {
    // some code like as follows
    for(auto x : a) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(auto x : b) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

Obviously, the following code fails with `error: no matching function for call to 'func(int [2], int [3])'`:

```
int a1[] = {1, 2};
int a2[] = {3, 4, 5};
func(a1, a2);
```

I cannot alter the function signature but I can overload it. I also want to avoid unnecessary copies too. My attempt was to write an overload like:

```
template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
void func(const T (&a)[M], const T (&b)[N]) {
    //somehow calling f<T>(const T&, const T&) without copying array elements
}
```

But, I am not sure how to implement it. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Live [demo](http://ideone.com/c9oYnr) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370298/2229960).

Comment: I don't see any reason why the body of your original function wouldn't work, but if you want to avoid copies, making copies as you loop through the containers isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a `range<T*>` structure to wrap your array, and define `begin()` and `end()` functions for it.

It can be as simple as

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct range { Iterator begin_, end_; };

template<typename T>
T begin(const range<T>& ar) { return ar.begin_; }

template<typename T>
T end(const range<T>& ar) { return ar.end_; }

template<typename T, size_t N>
range<T*> make_array_range(T (&array)[N])
{
     using std::begin; using std::end;
     return { begin(array), end(array) };
}

func( make_array_range(a1), make_array_range(a2) );
```

You can then easily write your `func(T[N], T[M])` overload using this building block.

You could also write a templated (on `N`) constructor if you don't like the factory function approach.

It can be used in place of any standard container because it supports the `begin`/`end` operations.  And it can refer to a whole array, contiguous subset of an array, or to a contiguous subsequence of any standard container.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/c9oYnr) to show how I wrapped this in my overload of `func` and it works just as I wanted!

Comment: @EissaN: There's actually a proposal to have the C++ standard library algorithms use range objects similar to this everywhere currently `begin` and `end` iterators are passed.

Comment: I can imagine that would be very useful. Thanks for the news.

Answer (score 0):

> somehow calling f(const T&, const T&) without copying array
>   elements

That, of course, won't work since that template function returns two parameters of the same type.

What you ***do*** need to do is to simply pass the arrays as pointers, and give the size of each corresponding array. After all, the very first thing one learns about arrays is that an array is convertible to a pointer to the first element of the array. so:

```
template<class T>
void func(const T *a, const T *b, size_t a_size, size_t b_size) {

   // ...
}
```

Now, your

```
template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
void func(const T (&a)[M], const T (&b)[N])
```

should be able to simply do something like this:

```
func(&a[0], &b[0], M, N);
```

You "real" `func()` will then know the size of each array.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use forwarding references:

```
template<class T, class U>
void func(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    for(auto x : a)
        cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;

    for(auto x : b)
        cout << x << " ";
}
```

Then you can pass your other container, or your C-style array. The parameter is passed by reference , so the array length information is available.

NB. Consider using `auto&&` or `auto const &` in the loops, to avoid making copies of the elements in the container.

Comment: I am not allowed to alter original `func` but I can just overload it. I can overload it with the way you suggest but the implementation that calls the original `func` is still non-trivial to me.

Comment: The "forwarding references" are unimportant here.  Simply changing to two template type parameters is the only change in behavior needed.